# get column names from stored procedure for displaying in html table using php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to display html table from a stored procedure using PDO.Resultset contains lot of columns and rows which needs to be exported to an excel. 
But I need to get the column names to be on the first row, how can be possible on the below code? Any help ?

```
   $q= $db->prepare( "CALL spalldetails" );
   $q->execute();

   while ($arrValues = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
   {
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach ($arrValues as $key=>$value)
        {   
            $column_names[]=$key;
    ?>

      <td><?=$value?></td>  
       <?
         }
     echo "</tr>";

        }
```

The below code displays the column name, but I want it to be the top row of the table.

```
echo "<tr>";
foreach ($column_names as $name)
{ ?>
    <td>
    <?=$name?>
    </td>
<? 
}
 echo "</tr>";
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question has nothing to do with stored procedures, as it's applicable to any data returned from database.

the most convenient way would be to fetch the data first, get the column names from the first row and then print the data.

besides, use of prepare execute is not justified for this query

```
$data = $db->query( "CALL spalldetails" )->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$column_names = array_keys($data[0]);
```

here you have your column names before output which you can make using foreach() instead of while()

Comment: i am using while ($arrValues = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) as i need to print <tr> for each row.

Comment: now you can change it to `foreach ($data as $arrValues)`, keeping rest of the code the same

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest instead of printing the output immediately while processing the through the for loop, you rather create a string to output later. This can be accomplished simply like this: (mind you the below is untested air code, but to show you an example of what I mean)

```
$q= $db->prepare( "CALL spalldetails" );
    $q->execute();

    while ($arrValues = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $tablestring .= "<tr>";
    foreach ($arrValues as $key=>$value){   
        $column_names[]=$key;
       $tablestring .= "<td>".$value."</td>";
     }
 $tablestring .= "</tr>";
}

$headstring .= "<tr>";
foreach ($column_names as $name)
{   $headstring .= "<td>".$name."</td>";
    }
 $headstring .= "</tr>";

echo "<table>".$headstring.$tablestring."</table>";
```